# Is there reverse of 'override' specifier in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, overriding

`override` keyword allows to make sure that the function will get overridden.
I am looking for the reverse functionality. So that - when I write a new function - I want to mark it with something to make sure it will not get accidentally overwritten.

(Also, I do not want to make it `static`, since it looks like to belong to an object rather than class)

Comment: What, like [the `final` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)?

Comment: You want `final`?

Comment: afaik `override` makes sure that the function is overriding the one in the base class, not the other way around... correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: ... if you want to make sure that a function gets overridden you have to make it abstract (ie pure virtual)

Comment: I would edit the question to fix it, but I dont know how to do it without changing it completely, because the way you describe `override` is already the reverse of its actual meaning (but not in the sense you are looking for)

Comment: If you don't want a function to be overridden, don't mark it `virtual`.

Comment: what if there is massive inheritance tree that my class derives from? Going everywhere and checking everything for virtual is a massive work. If I find that I am overriding it - yes I will remove it. But I need a speedy and clear indicator that that is happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to mark it with something to make sure it will not get accidentally overwritten.

You can use the [`final` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final). Example from **cppreference**:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void foo();
};

struct A : Base
{
    void foo() final; // A::foo is overridden and it is the final override
    void bar() final; // Error: non-virtual function cannot be overridden or be final
};
```

Comment: I want to make sure I am not overriding anything from parent classes

Comment: final helps only for classes that will derive from me

Comment: @DraifKroneg: you can mark the parent class's methods as `final`. If you do not have access to the parent class's definition there's no way of preventing overriding.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want a virtual function to be overridden in the derived class, you can use [final](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final):

> Specifies that a virtual function cannot be overridden in a derived class or that a class cannot be inherited from.

e.g.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void foo() final; // foo cannot be overridden in the derived class
};
struct Derived : Base
{
    void foo();               // Error: foo cannot be overridden as it's final in Base
};
```

Comment: What if I have hundreds of parent classes in inheritance tree? I just want to make sure I am not accidentally overriding anything from there. I cannot go through all of them and mark each of them final. I just want to add small function and get quick compilation error if it overrides anything.

Comment: In summary: 'overrides' keyword is local to my current function, while 'final' requires changes to me made potentially in many hundreds classes. It is not the same - It is doing quite a different thing from what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

`final` is the keyword you are looking for.

Remark: Be aware that `override` does not "make sure that the function will get overriden" as you put it. `override` in your **derived** class does make sure that you actually override a method of a base class, and not just introduce a new method that is similar to a virtual method of the base class.

To make sure that a method is overriden it would have to be pure virtual in your base class.

Also, `static` works exactly the other way round: static methods belong to the class, non-static methods need an object to be called.